When and how did the definition of continuity in terms of function's oscillation come into picture?
In this Wikipedia article, it is described how the oscillation of a function can be used to characterize the function having a limit. So, we say a function is continuous at a point when if its oscillation at the point is zero.
Historically, where does this definition come from? and what was the motivation for rewriting the limit in terms of the oscillation initially?

It never really did, almost nobody uses oscillation for a definition of continuity, not even Wikipedia's own source, Trench's Real Analysis text. But the concept of oscillation was introduced by Baire in 1897 to study functions that are pointwise limits of sequences of continuous functions, and he was aware that one can characterize continuity in terms of it. This line of thought led him to classification of what is now called Baire functions in his 1899 dissertation. The concept was picked up by Lebesgue and Young, and Lebesgue proved his Riemann integrability criterion (one of the most popular applications of the oscillation now) in his doctoral dissertation Intégrale, Longueur, Aire (1902). I should mention that Jordan talked about function's "oscillation" earlier, in Sur la série de Fourier (1881), but what he meant by that was total variation.
Baire's work is discussed in Medvedev's Scenes from the History of Real Functions, pp. 157ff:

"The problem of characterizing the class of discontinuous functions that are limits of everywhere convergent sequences of continuous functions came onto the agenda. It was this problem that Baire undertook to study starting in 1897.
Baire [1] began with the problem of the connection between the continuity of a function of two variables in each argument separately and its continuity jointly in the two variables. Introducing the concept of a semicontinuous
function and the oscillation of a function at a point [1, p. 694], he solved the problem just posed using these concepts... In [1] Baire succeeded in obtaining only certain particular results. Evidently the principal reason for his lack of success was an insufficiently general approach
to the definition of semicontinuity and to the concepts of oscillation and pointwise discontinuity of a function, which were studied in [1] only for intervals.


But by the following note [2], having defined these concepts in relation
to an arbitrary perfect set, he obtained the fundamental result, now known as Baire's Theorem on functions of first class... this theorem immediately caught the attention of mathematicians. Baire himself, in [2], merely indicated
an outline of the proof of the theorem just quoted. In the following year he devoted almost the entire second chapter of his dissertation [5, pp. 19-63] to it, and then returned to its proof at least three more times. Lebesgue and
Young each gave several proofs of this theorem, as did many mathematicians after them."

Baire's notes [1] and [2] are Sur la theorie generale des fonctions de variables reelles, Comptes Rendus, 125 (1897) 691-694; and Sur les fonctions discontinues developpables en series de fonctions continues, 126 (1898) 884-887. His 1899 dissertation Sur les fonctions de variables réelles discusses oscillation from p.7 on.

@tryst with freedom: The early origins of the oscillation of a function are discussed in my answer to Riemann's Contribution to Integration. If anyone is interested, some more recent and refined work involving the oscillation of a function are discussed in my answer to the MSE question Oscillation of a Function.
